# What's really going on with shared objects?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to test for the existence of a .sol file, which may or may not have been written by my program.

In a test program, let's say that my shared object is defined like this:

```
var mySharedObject = SharedObject('foldername'+'/StoredItem');
```

and I write the .sol like this:

```
mySharedObject.data.storedthing = 'storeddatum';
mySharedObject.flush();
```

Once I've written the sol, when I try to test if it exists with:

```
    if(mySharedObject.data.storedItem)
```

I get a 'yes' whether or not the file is actually there! That is, if I delete the sol file manually before I run the test, the test still comes up positive! If I run

```
    mySharedObject.clear()
```

before I do the test I get a 'no', which is what you'd expect. But then, even if I manually replace an exact copy of the sol back into the appropriate folder, I still get a 'no'!

It's as if AS3 won't actually read the file but rather reads the shared object as a static variable. This is a pain because otherwise I have to test for the existence of the sol using the File class.

Any ideas about what  'if(mySharedObject.data.storedItem)' is actually doing?

Comment: Only Adobe team could tell you for sure, but it is very possible that Flash Player reads the **SOL** file at the moment you **getLocal(...)** it then keeps it in the memory without actually touching the original file for purposes other than write intents. Thus if you want to always be aware of what's going on with the file, you need a wrapper class that always opens a new copy of Shared Object, then discards it after read/write operation. Which might also not work if Flash Player caches the accessed Shared Objects.

Comment: It looks like you're right. On further testing it's clear that the 'SharedObject.getLocal(...)' item is read from the file only if it is not in memory at the moment that it's first accessed. Once it's read it doesn't matter how the file is changed: the original value of the data, as it was first read from the .sol file, remains in memory and continues to be read, even if the .sol file is manually deleted from disk but not cleared. Clear() seems to be an operation that clears the memory AND deletes the file.

Comment: Yep. Expected that. SO is a cookie thing, you read it on app start then write it on app exit. It's not a convenient communication interface between AS3 application and a file.